# How to retrieve an object that was just created in Tastypie

Tags: django, backend, tastypie

Using Tastypie and Django User Streams, I am trying to build an activity feed. I have successfully built the functionality for favoriting below:

```
class LikeResource(ModelResource):
user = fields.ForeignKey(BasicUserResource, 'user', full=True)  
class Meta:
    queryset = Journalist.objects.all()
    allowed_methods = ['get', 'put']
    resource_name = 'like'
    fields = ['user']
    default_format = "application/json"
    authorization = Authorization()
    authentication = BasicAuthentication()
    serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
    always_return_data = True
    include_resource_uri = False

def hydrate(self, bundle):
    shot = LifeShot.objects.all().get(id = bundle.data['post id'])
            if(bundle.obj.likes.filter(id = bundle.data['post id']).exists()):
                 bundle.obj.likes.remove(shot)
            else:
                 bundle.obj.likes.add(shot)
                 user_doing_the_liking=User.objects.get(username=bundle.request.user.username)
                 user_getting_liked = shot.journalist.user
                 user_streams.add_stream_item(user_getting_liked, '%s liked your shot %s %s' % (bundle.request.user.username, shot.url, datetime.datetime.utcnow()))
            return bundle

    def dehydrate(self, bundle):
         shot = LifeShot.objects.all().get(id = bundle.data ['post id'])
         user_getting_liked = shot.foodie.user
         likeitems = user_streams.get_stream_items(user_getting_liked)
         list = ''
         for likeitem in likeitems:
              list = list + likeitem.content +', '
         bundle.data['likestream'] = list
         return bundle
```

Now for commenting on a photo, this is what I have so far:

```
class CommentEntryResource(ModelResource):
user = fields.ForeignKey(BasicJournalistResource, 'user', full =True)
picture = fields.ForeignKey(BasicLifeShotResource, 'picture', full=True)
class Meta:
    queryset = Comment.objects.all()
    allowed_methods = ['post', 'get','put']
    resource_name = 'comment'
    fields = ['comment', 'picture', 'user']
    authorization = Authorization()
    authentication = BasicAuthentication()
    serializer = Serializer(formats=['json'])
    include_resource_uri = False
    always_return_data = True

    filtering = {
            'picture': ALL_WITH_RELATIONS,
    }

def hydrate_user(self, bundle):

    bundle.data['user'] = Journalist.objects.get(user = bundle.request.user)


    return bundle
```

The only difference here now is that Tastypie has created a new comment object. How can I retrieve that comment object and implement it with Django User streams so that in my feed, it says "User1 commented on your shot: Looks Nice!" ???

Django User Streams: https://github.com/dabapps/django-user-streams
Tastypie: http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this as:

```
 bundle.data['user'] = Journalist.objects.get(user = bundle.obj.user)
```

`bundle.obj` will give you the `Comment` model object. You can the get the user by `bundle.obj.user`.